# System.Indexoutofrangeexception in For Statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception

I am writing a parser and this exception happened. Here is the code

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
        If TextBox2.Lines(i).StartsWith("print") = True Then
            Dim str1 As String = TextBox2.Lines(i).ToString.Replace("print", "echo")
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + str1
        ElseIf TextBox2.Lines(i) = "selfping" Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "ping 127.0.0.1"
        ElseIf TextBox2.Lines(i) = "pause empty" Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "pause >nul"
        ElseIf TextBox2.Lines(i) = "clear" Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "cls"
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + TextBox2.Lines(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This applied to every single If and ElseIf statements.

Comment: `TextBox2.Lines(i)` - that looks like an array

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am inexperienced and I can't tell whats an array or not.

Comment: is `TextBox1` a multi line textbox?

Comment: You are checking for the number of lines in TextBox1 then iterating through TextBox2's Line Collection, how do you know that you actually have the same number of lines in TextBox2 as you have in TextBox1?

Comment: It is because each line in TextBox1 represents each line in textbox2. I coded it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The Textbox2 is supposed to be textbox1. I should really get a code analyser.